# how to fix position of slide2 and overflow of transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please I am trying to to solve this problem but I can't do it , the problem is I can't change the position on specific location that I put it on slide2

And also the animation of sliding if overflowing outside the slide2 div

Please can anyone help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name=" Description" content="Example site">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="background_opacity">
            <div class="left">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="programming-coding-icon-free-vector.jpg" alt="logo" height="30px" width="30px"></li>
                    <li>Studio</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#project_tab">Project</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about_tab">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#awards_tab">Awards</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="fristsection">
            <div class="slide1">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide2">
                <div class="item2"></div>
                <div class="item2"></div>
                <div class="item2"></div>
                <div class="item2"></div>
                <div class="item2"></div>
                <div class="item2"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(59, 72, 130), rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(59, 72, 130));
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

body ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.background_opacity {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(57, 26, 86, 0.6);
    z-index: 100;
}
.background_opacity ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.background_opacity ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 30px;
}

.background_opacity ul li a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: aliceblue;
}

.background_opacity ul li a:visited {
    color: aliceblue;
}

.background_opacity ul li a:hover {
    color: rgb(149, 52, 176);
    font-size: 1.02rem;
}

.left {
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}

.right {
    font-size: 1.0rem;
}

.fristsection {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1500px;
    /* position: relative; */
}

.slide1 {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: -70px;
    height: 1570px;
    width: 50%;
}

.slide1 .item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    transform: -0%;
    animation: slide1 54s infinite;
}

.slide1 .item:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url('LONG\ IMG.jpg');
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

.slide1 .item:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url('LONG\ IMG\ 5.jpg');
    animation-delay: -10s;
}

.slide1 .item:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url('LONG\ IMG\ 4.jpg');
    animation-delay: -20s;
}

.slide1 .item:nth-child(4) {
    background-image: url('LONG\ IMG\ 3.jpg');
    animation-delay: -30s;
}

.slide1 .item:nth-child(5) {
    background-image: url('LONG\ IMG\ 2.jpg');
    animation-delay: -40s;
}

.slide1 .item:nth-child(6) {
    background-image: url('LONG\ IMG.jpg');
    animation-delay: -50s;
}

@keyframes slide1 {

    0%,
    12%,
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease;

    }

    20% {
        transform: translateX(-1000px);
        animation-timing-function: step-end;
    }

    92% {
        transform: translateX(0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease;
    }
}

.slide2 {
    position: absolute;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    width: 200px;
    height: 750px;
    top: 750px;
    left: 1000px;
}

.slide2 .item2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 750px;
    top: 750px;
    left: 1000px;
    background-size: cover;
    transform: -0%;
    animation: slide2 54s infinite;
    /* animation-delay:-5s initial; */
}

.slide1 .item2:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url('LONG\ IMG.jpg');
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

.slide1 .item2:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url('LONG\ IMG\ 5.jpg');
    animation-delay: -10s;
}

.slide2 .item2:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url('LONG\ IMG\ 4.jpg');
    animation-delay: -20s;
}

.slide2 .item2:nth-child(4) {
    background-image: url('LONG\ IMG\ 3.jpg');
    animation-delay: -30s;
}

.slide2 .item2:nth-child(5) {
    background-image: url('LONG\ IMG\ 2.jpg');
    animation-delay: -40s;
}

.slide2 .item2:nth-child(6) {
    background-image: url('LONG\ IMG.jpg');
    animation-delay: -50s;
}

@keyframes slide2 {

    0%,
    12%,
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease;

    }

    20% {
        transform: translateX(-1200px);
        animation-timing-function: step-end;
    }

    92% {
        transform: translateX(0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease;
    }
}
```

and i also want to add  another 4 slide div with different size that is

```
.slide3{
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    top: 1160px;
    left: 1250px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 252, 252, 0.1);
    border-radius: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.slide4{
    width: 200px;
    height: 230px;
    top: 1340px;
    left: 1250px;
}
.slide5{
    width: 200px;
    height: 630px;
    top: 940px;
    left: 1500px;
}
.slide6{
    width: 100px;
    height: 750px;
    top: 820px;
    left: 1750px;
}
```

Actually I want to create and sliding animation from one slide2 to slide1, in that animation but I don't know how to do on javascript, please can anyone send another answer with javascipt code